# Adding BackImage to Windows Chart from Resource Files

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to add a background image to a chart object from my local resource files. Apparently, WinForms is dumb and instead of letting me use a image, it wants a string to the location of that file instead. Below is a section of code of code that tells me "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'string'"... Any ideas?

```
private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myChart.BackImage = myProject.Properties.Resources.myBackgroundImage;
}
```

Comment: Are you using MSChart or from any vendor? The property BackImage does not looks like it follows Microsoft standard

Comment: @Anand It seems to be MS Chart and since the chart is designed to also support web charts, it expects a path or name as image.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I just felt this API name looks odd. It should be BackgroundImage

Comment: @Anand, there is BackgroundImage property, but msdn states that: _The BackgroundImage property is not used. Use the BackImage property instead._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

(...)

    var backImage= new NamedImage("bgImg",  myProject.Properties.Resources.myBackgroundImage);
    myChart.Images.Add(backImage);
    myChart.BackImage = "bgImg";
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it has to be so convoluted... Why they (Microsoft) couldn't just overload the setBackImage property to accept an image or a string is beyond me. Marked as answer :)